# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

i'm trying to run following script:

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()

mydb = ["Games"]
mycol = ["pcgames"]

data = {"Title": "Hollow Knight", "rating": 10}
mycol.insert_one(data)
```

but i'm getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\brend\onedrive - ict medien produktive umgebung\informatik\luratti\luratti.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pymongo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'
```

i already installed pymongo with pip install pymongo and also have mongodb connected.

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: A full `Traceback` may also be useful to understand the error.

Comment: did you install pymongo, try `pip list | grep pymongo` to find it

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't installed pymongo in your system.

You can do so by using the following command:

```
python -m pip install pymongo
```